# QUOTENAME is causing conversion errors in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

EDIT:

ok this is really throwing me off now, I have the query working twice and then for no reason it stops working again and give me different errors each time. Now I am getting this error:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Procedure gsp_rpt_Custom_Extract_Haven_test_2, Line 12
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.
```

It is so inconsistent, I can take out certain joins and the query runs but those join are completely irrelevant to the error and work absolutly fine independantly. Seriously confused about this one.

END EDIT

I have this query, its a fairly lengthy one. I am using the query for a BCP command which is why it looks odd. I am trying to add a text qualifier (as BCP cannot do it) by using quotename(), the query runs fine without the quote name for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure gsp_rpt_Custom_Extract_test, Line 12
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '05-01-2015 12:49:05' to data type smallint.
```

As you can see for the query i have commented out the columns I have not got to yet as a part of my diagnosis. All the columns work ok up until the last one (the case statement) is whats causing the problem. But like I said above, the querty runs fine when I remove all the quotenames.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Full code:

```
WITH QUEST_CTE AS (

SELECT CompanyID AS Company_ID, Q.QuestionID, QuestionText, CAST(Q.Answer AS VARCHAR) AS Answer
FROM Questionnaire AS Q
JOIN CallCentre_Web.dbo.Questionnaire_Questions QQ
ON Q.QuestionID = QQ.QuestionID
JOIN dbo.ProfileMapping AS PM
ON PM.ProfileMappingID = Q.ProfileMappingID
JOIN CampaignMapping AS CM
ON PM.MapID = CM.MapID
WHERE QuestionTypeID = 0
AND QQ.GoldenField = 1
AND CampaignID = 18
UNION ALL

SELECT CompanyID AS Company_ID, Q.QuestionID, QuestionText, CAST(QA.Answer AS VARCHAR) 
FROM Questionnaire AS Q
JOIN CallCentre_Web.dbo.Questionnaire_Questions QQ
ON Q.QuestionID = QQ.QuestionID
JOIN CallCentre_Web.dbo.Questionnaire_Answers QA
ON Q.Answer = QA.AnswerID
JOIN dbo.ProfileMapping AS PM
ON PM.ProfileMappingID = Q.ProfileMappingID
JOIN CampaignMapping AS CM
ON PM.MapID = CM.MapID
WHERE QuestionTypeID = 1
AND QQ.GoldenField = 1
AND CampaignID = 18
UNION ALL

SELECT CompanyID AS Company_ID, Q.QuestionID, QuestionText,
        CAST(STUFF((select ',' + e.Answer
        FROM Questionnaire a
        cross apply dbo.SplitString(a.Answer,',') b 
        join CallCentre_Web.dbo.Questionnaire_Answers e 
        on b.s = e.AnswerID
        where isnumeric(b.s) = 1 
        and QuestionTypeID = 2 
        and a.QuestionnaireID = q.QuestionnaireID
        for xml path('')),1,1,'') as Varchar) as Answer
FROM Questionnaire AS q
JOIN dbo.ProfileMapping AS PM
ON PM.ProfileMappingID = Q.ProfileMappingID
JOIN CampaignMapping AS CM
ON PM.MapID = CM.MapID
JOIN CallCentre_Web.dbo.Questionnaire_Questions QQ
ON Q.QuestionID = QQ.QuestionID
WHERE QuestionTypeID = 2
AND QQ.GoldenField = 1
AND CampaignID = 18
)

select CAST(Quotename('GS Id',char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('CompanyName', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('Address', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('Country',  char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('SicDescription',  char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('Sector', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('Employees',  char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('Website', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('CompanyTurnover', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('Phone',  char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('MobilePhone', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('Fax',  char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('Salutation',  char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('Forename',  char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('Surname',  char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('Jobtitle', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('EmailAddress', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
CAST(Quotename('LeadSource', char(34))as Varchar(255))
--CAST(Quotename('CallResult', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
--CAST(Quotename('What is your company registration number?', char(34))as Varchar(255))
--CAST(Quotename('Who is your electricity supplier?', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
--CAST(Quotename('Number of sites', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
--CAST(Quotename('MPAN Number', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
--CAST(Quotename('Do you use Half Hourly Meters?', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
--CAST(Quotename('What is your average use for electricity? (in GWh)', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
--CAST(Quotename('Do you use a fixed or flexible contract for your electricity? (if over 20GWh)', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
--CAST(Quotename('What is your average spend on electricity?', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
--CAST(Quotename('Do you have any involvement with a TPI?', char(34))as Varchar(255)),
--CAST(Quotename('If so, who is your TPI Supplier?',char(34))as Varchar(255)),
--CAST(Quotename('Electricity Contract Expiry Date',char(34)) as Varchar(255))

union all


select
Quotename(cast(C.CompanyID as varchar(255)),char(34)),  
Quotename(CompanyName, char(34)),
Quotename(ISNULL(AddressLine1,'') + case when addressline1 is null then '' else ', ' end + ISNULL(AddressLine2,'') + case when addressline2 is null then '' else ', ' end + ISNULL(AddressLine3,'') + case when addressline3 is null then '' else ', ' end + ISNULL(Town,'') + case when town is null then '' else ', ' end + ISNULL(County,'') + case when county is null then '' else ', ' end + ISNULL(Region,'') + case when region is null then '' else ', ' end + Postcode, char(34)),
Quotename('UK', char(34)),
Quotename(SIC.SicDescription, char(34)),
Quotename(sec.Sector, char(34)),
cast(quotename(ISNULL(NumberOfEmployees,''),char(34)) as varchar(255)),
cast(Quotename(ISNULL(Website,''),char(34)) as Varchar(255)),
cast(Quotename(ISNULL(CompanyTurnover,''),char(34)) as varchar(255)),
Quotename(ISNULL(MainTel.Phonenumber,''),char(34)) ,
Quotename(ISNULL(MobTel.PhoneNumber,''),char(34)),
Quotename(ISNULL(FaxTel.PhoneNumber,''), char(34)),
Quotename(ISNULL(Salutation,''), char(34)),
Quotename(ISNULL(Forename,''), char(34)),
Quotename(ISNULL(Surname,''), char(34)),
Quotename(ISNULL(Jobtitle,''),char(34)),
Quotename(ISNULL(EmailAddress,''),char(34)),
CASE  WHEN [What is your average use for electricity? (in GWh)] >= 1.5 OR [What is your average spend on electricity?] >= 150000 THEN quotename('GS1',char(34))
      WHEN [What is your average use for electricity? (in GWh)] < 1.5 OR [What is your average spend on electricity?] < 150000 THEN quotename('GS1 SME',char(34))
      ELSE quotename('GS1',char(34)) END
--Quotename(CallResult,char(34))
--Quotename(ISNULL([What is your company registration number?],''),char(34))
--CASE WHEN ISNULL([Who is your electricity supplier?],'') = 'Other' THEN ISNULL([If other please state who (electric)],'')
--ELSE ISNULL([Who is your electricity supplier?],'') END,
--Quotename(ISNULL([Number of sites],''),char(34))
--ISNULL([MPAN Number],''),
--ISNULL([Do you use Half Hourly Meters?],'') ,
--ISNULL([What is your average use for electricity? (in GWh)],''),
--ISNULL([Do you use a fixed or flexible contract for your electricity? (if over 20GWh)],''),
--ISNULL([What is your average spend on electricity?],''),
--ISNULL([Do you have any involvement with a TPI?],''),
--ISNULL([If so, who is your TPI Supplier?],''),
--CAST(ISNULL(replace(convert(Varchar(10),[Electricity Contract Expiry Date],103),'-','/'),'') AS Varchar(20))
from company c
join callcentre_web.dbo.LK_SIC as sic
on sic.sicid = c.sicid
and sic.sictype = c.sictype
join callcentre_web.dbo.LK_Sector as sec
on sec.sectorid = sic.sectorid
and sic.sictype = sec.SectorType
left join ( 
            SELECT * FROM (
            select row_number() over (partition by companyID order by C.CompanyID) as ROW, 
            CompanyID, Surname , Forename , s.salutation, Emailaddress, Jobtitle
            from contacts as C
            join callcentre_web.dbo.lk_Salutation as s
            on c.salutation = s.salutationid
            join contactdetails as cd 
            on cd.contactid = c.contactid
            and campaignid = 18
            where responsibilityID = 3 /* PRIMARY CONTACT */
            ) x
            WHERE ROW = 1
           ) as Con
on Con.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
left join (
            SELECT * FROM (
            select row_number() over (partition by cn.companyID order by Cn.CompanyID) as ROW,
            cn.companyid, PhoneNumber
            from contactnumbers cn
            join company as c
            on c.companyid = cn.companyid
            join campaignmapping as cm
            on cm.companyid = c.companyid
            where phonetypeid not in (3,4,5)--Mobile, TPS, Fax
            and campaignid = 18
            ) x
            where row = 1
            ) AS MainTel
ON MainTel.companyid = C.companyID
left join (
            SELECT * FROM (
            select row_number() over (partition by cn.companyID order by Cn.CompanyID) as ROW,
            cn.companyid, PhoneNumber
            from contactnumbers cn
            join company as c
            on c.companyid = cn.companyid
            join campaignmapping as cm
            on cm.companyid = c.companyid
            where phonetypeid = 3--Mobile
            and PhoneNumber like '07%'
            and campaignid = 18
            ) x
            where row = 1
            ) AS MobTel
ON MobTel.companyid = C.companyID
left join (
            SELECT * FROM (
            select row_number() over (partition by cn.companyID order by Cn.CompanyID) as ROW,
            cn.companyid, PhoneNumber
            from contactnumbers cn
            join company as c
            on c.companyid = cn.companyid
            join campaignmapping as cm
            on cm.companyid = c.companyid
            where phonetypeid = 5--Fax
            and campaignid = 18
            ) x
            where row = 1
            ) AS FaxTel
ON FaxTel.companyid = C.companyID
join campaignmapping as cm
on cm.companyid = c.companyid
and CampaignID = 18
join calldetails as cd
on cd.mapid = cm.mapid
left join callcentre_web..lk_callresults as lkc
on lkc.callresultid = cd.callresultid
left join ( SELECT * FROM
                        (
                            SELECT Company_ID, QuestionText, Answer
                            FROM Quest_CTE
                        ) AS source
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Answer)
    FOR QuestionText IN ([What is your company registration number?],
[Who is your electricity supplier?],[Number of sites],[If other please state who (electric)],
[MPAN Number],[Do you use Half Hourly Meters?],
[Do you use a fixed or flexible contract for your gas? (if over 20GWh)],
[What is your average use for electricity? (in GWh)],
[Do you use a fixed or flexible contract for your electricity? (if over 20GWh)],
[What is your average spend on Gas?],[What is your average spend on electricity?],
[Do you have any involvement with a TPI?],[If so, who is your TPI Supplier?],
[Gas Contract expiry date],[Electricity Contract Expiry Date])
) as pvt
) AS PV 
ON PV.Company_ID = C.CompanyID
```

Comment: Its probably this: `--CAST(Quotename('Electricity Contract Expiry Date',char(34)) as Varchar(255))` ?

Comment: @StevieG: That line is commented, so it can't be the cause of the error.

Comment: Check you data, maybe you have left or right bracket ( [ ] ) somewhere in your data. Brackets are default delimiter for Quotename.